# Form submission blocked by bootstrapValidator

Tags: php, forms, block, submission, bootstrapvalidator

I have a problem when I try to submit a form which uses bootstrapValidator() for validating fields -> it doesn't submit, php file is not executed (I know that because I've tried without booststrapValidator and it works).
Any idea?

Form looks like this:

```
<form id="contactForm"  class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="contact_form.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"> 
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="msg">Mesage</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <textarea class="form-control col-sm-10" id="msg" name="msg" placeholder=""></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="captchaOperation" class="control-label col-sm-2" for="captcha"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="captcha" name="captcha" placeholder="Answer">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></button>` remove `</button>` it unnecessary but it will not make any difference, post bootstrap validator code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove from `id="submit" name="submit"` and `</button>` from

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></button>
```

add `data-toggle="validator"` in `<form>`

```
<form id="contactForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="contact_form.php" method="POST" data-toggle="validator">
```

so complete form will be

```
<form id="contactForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="contact_form.php" method="POST" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="msg">Mesage</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control col-sm-10" id="msg" name="msg" placeholder=""></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label id="captchaOperation" class="control-label col-sm-2" for="captcha"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="captcha" name="captcha" placeholder="Answer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and bootstrap validator code example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contactForm').bootstrapValidator({
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        excluded: [':disabled'],
        fields: {
            name: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Full Name field is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Email field is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            msg: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Message field is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            captcha: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Captcha field is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and it will submit the form after validation, actual reason form not submit after validation is `id="submit" name="submit"` inside `submit` button where type is also `type="submit"` ([Fiddle with name & id = submit](http://jsfiddle.net/tdLzsvpk/1/)) reason unknown why bootstrapvalidator not submit the form, possible a bug may be it got confused what to do with input where `type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"` so either remove `id="submit" name="submit"` ([Fiddle without name & id = submit](http://jsfiddle.net/tdLzsvpk/2/)) or change to something different then `type="submit"` like `id="sub" name="sub"` ([Fiddle with name & id = sub](http://jsfiddle.net/tdLzsvpk/3/))

Answer (score 0):

id and name "submit" were one of the problems, another one was this:

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
});
$("#sbm").on("click", function(){
 var bootstrapValidator = $("#contactForm").data('bootstrapValidator');
 bootstrapValidator.validate();

if(bootstrapValidator.isValid())
    //setTimeout(function(){$("#success").show();}, 300);
    error = true;
    $("#contactForm").submit();
else return;
});
```

I was trying to capture validator's return state and that prevent form from submitting. PS: I've tried without preventDefault() too but with no success at all so I've deleted all this code and now it works ok.